# Как ставить запятые в деепричастном обороте при наличии раскрытия (пояснения)?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, деепричастный-оборот, приложение

> Доехав до старой избушки(,) — дома Игоря Ивановича(,) — Олег окончательно успокоился.

Вроде бы у Розенталя было написано, что запятая ставится перед двумя тире, но я в сомнениях.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По всей видимости, нужно написать так:

*Доехав до старой избушки — **дома Игоря Ивановича,** Олег окончательно успокоился.*

> **10.** При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется **тире**:
> <...>
> **Примечание.** Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
> **1)** если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая: *Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — **весы,** то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — **акваланг,** можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров.*

Источник: [Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#) (справочник Розенталя).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146895/discussion-on-answer-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Странно, из-за семи (не 7-ми!) комментариев перенесли в чат.

Comment: Александр, да, придерживаюсь, просто привычка)) Кроме того, есть люди (среди авторов текстов), которые, напротив, требуют отсутствия точек. Но к точкам над буквой Ё отношусь положительно. Если хотите, могу оформить вопрос–ответ на эту тему. P.S. Да, из-за семи (не 7-ми!), но и одной цифрой это не запишешь тоже. Рекомендуется прописывать короткие числа, чтобы было понятно? Значит, логика понятной записи в наращениях все-таки просматривается... И это ответ на вопрос? Тогда вы можете оформить его...